# SMTP, can't send formatted text

Tags: c#, smtp

I am trying to send formatted text with `SMTP`. I'm sending it over as `HTML`, but when the email is sent it's a sent as a string normal text.

```
 foreach (var emailAddress in toEmailAddress)
                {
                    message.To.Add(emailAddress);
                }

                //remove special chars
                //emailMessage = emailMessage.Replace("\r\n", "<br/>");
                //emailMessage = emailMessage.Replace("\t", "");

                message.Subject = emailSubject;
                message.Body = emailMessage;
                message.From = sender;
                message.IsBodyHtml = true;
                message.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;



                //testing out with gmail
                using (var smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
                {
                    Credentials = new NetworkCredential("email", "Password"),
                    EnableSsl = true
                })
                {
                    await smtpClient.SendMailAsync(message);
                }
```

This is the Message Body I am having trouble formatting this.

```
"<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd\">
<br/>
     <html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">
          <br/>
          <head>
               <br/>
                     <meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\" />
                        <title>
                           <br/> 
                       </title>
                       <br/> 
                      <style type=\"text/css\">
                           <br/>
                        .cs95E872D0{text-align:left;text-indent:0pt;margin:0pt 0pt 0pt 0pt}                       <br/> 
                           .cs46E558AC{color:#F00000;background-color:transparent;font-family:Calibri;font-size:11pt;font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;text-decoration: underline;}
                             <br/>
                      </style><
                      br/>
           </head>
          <br/>  
         <body>
                  <br/> 
                       <p class=\"cs95E872D0\">
                             <span class=\"cs46E558AC\">This is red text that is underlined</span>
                       </p>
        </body>
<br/>
</html>
<br/>"
```

Comment: How are you checking that it's "sent" as normal text and not just received and displayed as normal text?

Comment: I tried this on my end, removed the `<br/>`'s, because they were weird anyhow and then it came through just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is sending as html. Cleaned up your br tags and send

here's the message received by gmail

```
Return-Path: <xxxxxxxx@gmail.com>
Received: from D2205 ([198.182.213.4])
        by smtp.gmail.com with ESMTPSA id e21sm6307299iof.23.2016.10.13.13.05.01
        for <xxxxxxxx@gmail.com>
        (version=TLS1 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA bits=128/128);
        Thu, 13 Oct 2016 13:05:01 -0700 (PDT)
Message-ID: <57ffe8ed.15b56b0a.4b5ca.81a7@mx.google.com>
Date: Thu, 13 Oct 2016 13:05:01 -0700 (PDT)
X-Google-Original-Date: 13 Oct 2016 16:05:01 -0400
MIME-Version: 1.0
From: xxxxxxxx@gmail.com
To: xxxxxxxx@gmail.com
Subject: Test email
Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "h=
ttp://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">     <htm=
l xmlns=3D"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">  <head>  <meta http-equ=
iv=3D"Content-Type" content=3D"text/html; charset=3Dutf-8" /> <ti=
tle>  </title>  <style type=3D"text/css">  .cs95E872D0{text-align=
:left;text-indent:0pt;margin:0pt 0pt 0pt 0pt}  .cs46E558AC{color:=
#F00000;background-color:transparent;font-family:Calibri;font-siz=
e:11pt;font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;text-decoration: unde=
rline;}  </style></head>  <body>  <p class=3D"cs95E872D0"> <spanc=
lass=3D"cs46E558AC">This is red text that is underlined</span> </=
p> </body></html>
```

Comment: You're right it is. It's just that `style` Tags aren't supported in gmail. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

need to read body from system.io.

```
messageBody = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("D:\\Demo\\test.html");
```

For smtp prop be sure isHtml is true and sending .html file's string

```
IsHtml = true,
Body = messageBody,
```

And your html must be like

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<style type="text/css">
    .cs95E872D0 {
        text-align: left;
        text-indent: 0pt;
        margin: 0pt 0pt 0pt 0pt;
    }

    .cs46E558AC {
        color: #F00000;
        background-color: transparent;
        font-family: Calibri;
        font-size: 11pt;
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;
        text-decoration: underline;
    }
</style>

<br />
<p class="cs95E872D">
    <span class="cs46E558AC">This is red text that is underlined</span>
</p>
```

Comment: @AKADER haha please don't do that

Comment: @KSib why he shouldn't do that ?

Comment: It's unecessary to involve reading from the disk at all. @Ayvaras

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the `style` tag. Gmail doesn't support it.